# spring websocket SessionDisconnectEvent

Tags: spring, spring-websocket

I want to detect disconnected users. I try to listen `SessionDisconnectEvent`, but `eventPublisher` in `StompSubProtocolHandler` is always null and it never publish.
I'm using 4.0.5

Comment: Can you share your Stomp configuration? I see the bottleneck with `StompSubProtocolHandler`, but want to be sure, if it has value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are - https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11825: it's really a bug.

As you see by comments from that JIRA, to fix it as a workaround you should configure WebSocket Broker `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` and JavaConfig instead of `<websocket:message-broker>` XML.

I think we'll take care of that soon.